# Copying multiple specific cells to specific ranges in new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I usually don't ask for help but I'd like to sort this out and it's making me crazy.

I have a Excel workbook with 2 sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2). Data in Sheet1 is what I need.

In Sheet1 I have several columns and rows with different data; I need to create a macro that allows to copy certains cells (all from a single row though) into a new Workbook based on a model (let's call it "model.xlst") but in certain cells.

i.e.: I need to copy, from row 5, values from cells corresponding to A5, C5 and H5. Then, I need to paste these data into a new Workbook.
Let's say for example:

- A5 from Sheet1 goes into B3 in new Workbook
- C5 from Sheet1 goes into F8 in new Workbook
- H5 from Sheet1 goes into H6 in new Workbook

Also I'd have to repeat the process for other rows, so I'd include a Dialog box to select the cell I want to start with. (this I managed at least!)

I tried a lot of scripts to achieve this process but I'm not getting to a point here.
If anyone could give me a start I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Giacomo

---

Edit: this is where I have got so far. As you can see I managed to create a new workbook, even though it isn't the model I want to use (it just creates a new blank workbook and opens the model at the same time), and I'm missing the whole cells selection and copy part, I tried a lot of things but they did not work. Really stuck here. I'm not so experienced in coding as you may see :)

```
Sub CopyToLog()
Dim SlctRange As Range, CopyRange As Range
Dim strTemplate As String: strTemplate = "MODELLO_LOGSHEET.xlsx"
Dim wb As Workbook
xTitleId = "SlctRange"
Set SlctRange = Application.Selection
Set SlctRange = Application.InputBox("Range to be selected :", xTitleId, SlctRange.Address, Type:=8)
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(strTemplate)
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
```

Comment: Please [edit] your original question and add the code you already have. Tell what you tried to do and where you got errors or where you got stuck.

Comment: So when you're selecting a cell, you can specify the `Workbook`, `Worksheet` and `Range` (or `Cells`). So when you add a new workbook, if you want to select some cells from the workbook with the macro, you can use `ThisWorkbook`. You specify each piece with a period in the middle. `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B3") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5")` That's how you could set the New workbook's `B3` range to the old workbook's `A5` range. I didn't know the sheet names so I simply said `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` (since you will have just added it with `Workbooks.Add`

Comment: Since you use `Set wb = Workbooks.Add` you can use `wb` to reference it like `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3") = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5")` That's how you select the cells and set the values when working with multiple workbooks and multiple worksheets. `ThisWorkbook` points to the workbook that is running your macro. `ActiveWorkbook` points to whichever workbook has focus.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll look into it tonight. I managed to copy and paste cells correctly to the new (blank for now) workbook so I think I'll sort it out soon!

Comment: Hi mate, I managed to include all the code I need, except the one that allows to create the NewWorkbook as a copy of an existing template. Could you help me on that?
At the moment it just opens the template and creates a new blank workbook where the copied cells are pasted.
Thanks in advance!